# I can't pass data between classes using callback as completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, callback, swift5

I want to pass text of textField in custom class to ViewController and populate it to array when BarButtonItem of DatePicker is tapped. I used a callback as completion handler, but it caught EXC-BAD-ACCESS. What made this error and how could I pass text to my ViewController?

- Custom class of textField

```
class HourDatePicker: UITextField {

    var datePicker =  UIDatePicker()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commominit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commominit()
    }

    func commominit(){
        text = ""
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
        datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setText), for: .valueChanged)
        setText()
        inputView = datePicker
        inputAccessoryView = customPicker()
     }

    @objc func setText(){
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.dateStyle = .full
        f.timeStyle = .short
        f.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")
        textColor = .black
        text = "\(f.string(from: datePicker.date))"

    }
    private func customPicker() -> UIToolbar {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 40)
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        space.width = 100
        let flexSpaceItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let todayButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "today", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(setToday))
        let selectButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "select", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(tellCalenderText))

        let toolbarItem = [space, flexSpaceItem, todayButtonItem, selectButtonItem]
         toolbar.setItems(toolbarItem, animated: true)
        }
        return toolbar
    }

    @objc func tellCalenderText(completion: ((_ titleText: String) -> Void)){
        //I want to pass text here.
        if text != "" {
        guard let titleText = text else {return}
        completion(titleText)
        } else {
            return
        }

    }
```

- ViewController

```
class Calender1ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let selectDate = HourDatePicker()
    private var keepDate: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var timeTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateText: HourDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var calenderTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.calenderTableView.delegate = self
        self.calenderTableView.dataSource = self

        selectDate.tellCalenderText {[weak self] (titleText) in
            self?.bringDate(title: titleText)
        }


    }

    func bringDate(title: String){

        print("title: \(title)")
        self.keepDate.append(title)
        timeTextView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(title)\n")

    }
```

Thank you.

This is error log.
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Wil.jpg)

Comment: post the complete crash log of EXC_BADAccess to get better idea on what might be causing error

Comment: I am quite certain that you didn't link your timeTextView. It crashes because it is nil :)

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari I don' know much about crash log. Is that image right?

Comment: @ Andriy Gordiychuk The link is about IBOutlet? I checked but it was sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you're getting a bit messed up by having:

```
private let selectDate = HourDatePicker()
```

***and*** having:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateText: HourDatePicker!
```

and then making use of `selectDate` inside `viewDidLoad()`...

Give this a try. I only made a few changes, and tried to include enough comments to make it clear. I think you'll find this a much more straight-forward way of getting your custom `HourDatePicker` class to pass information back to the view controller:

```
class HourDatePicker: UITextField {

    var datePicker =  UIDatePicker()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commominit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commominit()
    }

    func commominit(){
        text = ""
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
        datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setText), for: .valueChanged)
        setText()
        inputView = datePicker
        inputAccessoryView = customPicker()
    }

    @objc func setToday(){
        datePicker.date = Date()
    }

    @objc func setText(){
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.dateStyle = .full
        f.timeStyle = .short
        f.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")
        textColor = .black
        text = "\(f.string(from: datePicker.date))"

    }
    private func customPicker() -> UIToolbar {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 40)
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        space.width = 100
        let flexSpaceItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let todayButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "today", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(setToday))
        let selectButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "select", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(tellCalenderText))

        let toolbarItem = [space, flexSpaceItem, todayButtonItem, selectButtonItem]
        toolbar.setItems(toolbarItem, animated: true)
        return toolbar
    }

    // "callback" closure
    var tellController: ((String) ->())?

    // triggered by "select" bar button tap
    @objc func tellCalenderText() -> Void {
        // get text from self
        guard let t = text else {
            return
        }
        // execute the callback closure
        tellController?(t)
    }

//  @objc func tellCalenderText(completion: ((_ titleText: String) -> Void)){
//      //I want to pass text here.
//      if text != "" {
//          guard let titleText = text else {return}
//          completion(titleText)
//      } else {
//          return
//      }
//
//  }
}

//ViewController
class Calender1ViewController: UIViewController {

    // not needed
    //private let selectDate = HourDatePicker()

    private var keepDate: [String] = []

    // UITextView connected via Storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var timeTextView: UITextView!

    // UITextField set to HourDatePicker, connected via Storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var dateText: HourDatePicker!

    @IBOutlet weak var calenderTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set the callback closure for the HourDatePicker
        dateText.tellController = { [weak self] (titleText) in
            self?.bringDate(title: titleText)
        }

        // not needed
        //selectDate.tellCalenderText {[weak self] (titleText) in
        //  self?.bringDate(title: titleText)
        //}

    }

    func bringDate(title: String){

        print("title: \(title)")
        self.keepDate.append(title)
        timeTextView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(title)\n")

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, DonMag. I didn't understand about closure and how to use it.